# Covariant derivative. Is this solution correct?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, proof-verification, vector-fields

$\textbf{Problem:}$ If $(u_1,u_2)$ are coordinates on a surface S, define the covariant derivatives $DV/\partial{u_i}$ of a vector field V in the $u_i$-direction, in terms of ordinary derivatives in $R^3$. Show that
$$
    \frac{\partial}{\partial{u_i}} \langle V, W \rangle 
    = \left\langle \frac{DV}{\partial{u_i}}, W \right\rangle + \left\langle V, \frac{DW}{\partial{u_i}} \right\rangle
   $$

To show the equality, I wrote:

$$
    \left\langle \frac{DV}{\partial{u_i}}, W \right\rangle 
=\left\langle\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{u_i}} - \left(\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{u_i}} \cdot N\right)N, W\right\rangle
= \left\langle\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{u_i}}, W\right\rangle - \left(\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{u_i}} \cdot N\right) \langle N, W \rangle
   $$
            and the last term is zero since $W$ is in the tangent plane to which the normal is perpendicular. Similarly, we have
            $$
    \left\langle V, \frac{DW}{\partial{u_i}} \right\rangle
= \left\langle V, \frac{\partial{W}}{\partial{u_i}}\right\rangle
   $$
            It follows that
            $$
    \frac{\partial}{\partial{u_i}} \langle V, W \rangle 
    = \left\langle\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{u_i}}, W\right\rangle + \left\langle V, \frac{\partial{W}}{\partial{u_i}}\right\rangle
    = \left\langle \frac{DV}{\partial{u_i}}, W \right\rangle + \left\langle V, \frac{DW}{\partial{u_i}} \right\rangle
   $$

Comment: What do you mean by *"define the covariant derivatives [on $S$] in terms of ordinary derivatives in $\Bbb R^3$"*? Are those fields and scalar products considered on $S$ or on $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: @AlexM. There is an answer to that here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2245846/covariant-derivatives-of-vector-field

Comment: Yes, @MathUser_NotPrime, this is fine.